# Need To Use Live CD With Mac without Shutting Down Computer (VMWare/Parallels Secure?)

Tags: privacy, macos

I've heard of using Live CDs such as Tails to protect yourself online. Is there a similar setup to this that would work except run a Mac OS? I've done some searching, but have yet to find anything.

EDIT: I said setup, not product.

Comment: What are you trying to defend against with a live CD? Tails's anonymity is because it uses Tor, not because it's run from live disk.

Comment: I thought the live disk added a layer of anonymity because it took out the factor have having the name of your computer being detected?

Comment: Nope. Computer name is really easy to change on any OS, and there's no reason a live disk would have to have a different name. For any network-based adversaries, a live disk makes literally zero difference -- there's no difference between running your computer from a little drive plugged in over USB and running your computer from something installed to a partition of the hard drive. Live disks can help to ensure you aren't carrying over anything between sessions, but that's not guaranteed on a USB stick and there's no reason you couldn't do that without one.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong...essentially, Tails is just for if you're on a public computer and cannot download the Tor browser? Hypothetically speaking, if someone were able to locate the computer, it would still show the computer's name/metadata instead of just showing it is an instance of Tails (thus masking the name/metadata of the the host computer). Right? So it sounds like if I just use the Tor browser with my Mac, that will be just as good.

Comment: @cpast I think you are missing an important point about the live CD... Using it you won't be leaving traces in the computer like you do with other installed OS. So, no, you wont be "just as good" if someone can get your computer after you used it. EDIT: I know OP asked about ONLINE PRIVACY, I just think that saying "it's the samething" might cause some confussion in general.

Comment: OK. @JhulianoMoreno...If someone were to pentrate my VPN/TOR set up, could they find out the meta data of the computer I am using? Or does Tails keep that separate? People are always saying just use Tails to browse anonymously, but if they can see my computer meta data anyways, then what's the point? Same question goes for the below response.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a MacOS as a Live CD?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tails with Mac OS by using a virtual machine! Think about it this way: in a situation where you want to preserve your privacy, you want to set up your operating system so that it can be wiped/thrown away quickly. That's why so many folks like to do their private operations off live USBs or virtual machines.

Here are a few ideas:

- Use a live USB to boot into tails at start up.
- Keep an encrypted VMWare image of tails to use while browsing, with proper preparations to delete it if and when necessary. Always keep it fully encrypted when not in use.
- Always use full disk encryption on your mac. Turn it off and keep it encrypted when you can.

Comment: Would this scenario work: Have an instance of parallels running (I have parallels, but not VMWare). Boot Tails from Parallels. Have VPN on Tails for added layer of protection. Then I would be allowed to shift between Mac for personal, then browse privately with Tails without having to reset my computer.

NOTE: I always have a feeling someone could tell who I am through my Parallels/VMWare registration if I did this. Can you assure me that they wouldn't be able to do this?

Comment: Well, it would be very hard. They would have to compromise your machine to see your VM details. Paralells/VMWare doesn't exactly advertise your creds. If you're worrying about the sort of person with the skills to remotely compromise VMWare, and the motivation to do it to you, then maybe you boot from a liveUSB. That would be a very *determined* attacker.

Comment: Summary (Can you confirm?): Running Tails from Parallels/VMWare is secure...I can transfer files between my Mac and virtual machine with no problem. My Mac will allow me to stay personal, the virtual machine will give me privacy. I don't have to reboot or do anything otherwise.

Comment: https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/index.en.html - Long story short, the danger is mostly on the client side. From the remote side (servers watching you) you are in good shape. The issue the Tails folk point out is that tails leave artifacts on your Mac from VM. I would personally feel ok about that (I encrypt everything anyway, and always encrypt the hard disk when I'm away.) But it's up to you to decide if you need to go with a live USB for optimal results.